# Como verificar se há um UserControl em um Panel? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, panel, usercontrol

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que tem um Panel central, e por ele estou controlando os UserControls, estou usando Clear, Add e BringToFront para manipular, eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma função para que eu consiga verificar se um UserControl específico já foi adicionado no meu Panel, um exemplo, em dois UserControls diferentes eu adiciono um mesmo UserControl no Panel, então eu quero que se eu já tiver adicionado, eu não precise adicionar de novo, apenas dou um BringToFront por que um desses dois UserControls já vai ter adicionado esse novo UserControl no Panel, quero fazer uma verificação antes de dar o comando Panel.Controls.Add()...

Pegando carona nessa questão, tem algum método para remover apenas UM UserControl do Panel? Sem ser com o Clear(), porque ele limpa o painel todo, então eu perderia algumas informações de outros UserControls que já foram abertos... Me desculpem caso tenha ficado muito difícil entender minha dúvida, agradeço se alguem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Procurei a minha dúvida em English e encontrei as devidas respostas no Stack gringo.

**Verificar se um UserControl está adicionado no Panel:**

```
if(panel.Controls.Contais(myUserControl))
{

}
```

**Remover um UserControl específico**

```
panel.Controls.Remove(myUserControl);
```